# Alternate way to arrange barplot (geom_bar)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot a box plot using ggplot, I get a plot like this:

[image: plot before making additional data frame]

used R code:

```
ggplot(nin) + geom_bar(aes(Planner.Group.No))
```

But I wanted the bars to go from larger value to smaller, so I wrote these additional codes

```
b <- data.frame(table(x = nin$Planner.Group.No))
b <- arrange(b, Freq)

ggplot(b, aes(x = reorder(x, -Freq), y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: Desired plot]

I am wondering if there is an alternative way in ggplot where we can avoid the additional lines of code.

Here is a sample of the `nin` data set:

```
   Planner.Group.No Order.Status
1               P0B     Finished
2               P0C     Finished
3               P0C     Finished
4               P0A     Finished
5               P0C     Finished
6               P0B     Finished
7               P0C     Finished
```

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot2` prints factors in the order they are, hence you might also have a look at the two solutions below. One uses `factor` from `base`, the other uses `fct_reorder` from `forcats`, which I also like and use quite often because of its flexibility when I have to use custom order-function:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Planner.Group.No Order.Status
1               P0B     Finished
2               P0C     Finished
3               P0C     Finished
4               P0A     Finished
5               P0C     Finished
6               P0B     Finished
7               P0C     Finished", header = TRUE)
df


library(tidyverse) # for ggplot2 and forcats

# using factors
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Planner.Group.No, 
                          levels = names(sort(table(Planner.Group.No), decreasing = T))))) + 
  geom_bar()

# using factors with forcats:
ggplot(df, aes(x = fct_reorder(f = Planner.Group.No, 
                               x = Planner.Group.No, 
                               fun = length, 
                               .desc = TRUE))) + 
  geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `limits` parameter of `scale_x_discrete` a vector of x values in the order you'd like, so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

nin <- data.frame(Planner.Group.No = c("P0B", "P0C", "P0C", "P0A", "P0C", "P0B", "P0C"), 
                  Order.Status = c("Finished", "Finished", "Finished", "Finished", "Finished", "Finished", "Finished"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(nin, aes(Planner.Group.No)) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits = names(sort(-table(nin$Planner.Group.No))))
```

[image]